# Обратный вывод цифр через рекурсию

Tags: java, рекурсия

Написал простой код для обратного вывода цифр - т.е. вводится 1234, выводится 4321 :

```
public static int reverse (int num)
    {
        int reverse = 0;
        do
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10 + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        while(num != 0);
        return reverse;
    }
```

Мне бы хотелось получить то же, но без циклов, используя только рекурсию. Ничего не получается с тем же алгоритмом. Может, нужен другой алгоритм? Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: Нужно именно через рекурсию?

Answer (score 1):

Решил похоже на правду:
public static int reverse (int num)

```
{
        if (num < 10)
            return num ;
        else 
        {
            String numS = num + "";
            int len = numS.length() - 1;
            return (int) ((num % 10) * Math.pow(10, len) + reverse(num/10));            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```
static int revert( int num, int rc = 0 )
{
    rc = rc * 10 + num % 10;
    return num > 10 ? revert( num / 10, rc ) : rc;
}

/* ... */
int rc = revert( 1234 );
```

А смысл?

BTW, в исходном коде есть ошибочка, соответственно, здесь тоже :) Тест:

```
int rc = revert( 12340 );
```